# Is there a place/page where I can take a look all possible shapes in Visio?

Tags: uml, shapes, diagram, visio, tool-uml

There are many shape groups in Visio. I'm not so familiar with all of them.

I would like to take a look at all of them, preferably on a single page to find what I'm looking for.

[image: Visio shape selecting]

Comment: How in the world is this related to UML? Visio is no UML modeling tool at all.

Comment: @qwerty_so, why? I'd say Visio is about not only UML. It can help to make UML modeling and other diagram stuff.

Comment: Visio is a drawing tool. UML is not about diagrams.

Comment: I don't understand. This link says pretty clear https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uml-diagrams-in-visio-ca4e3ae9-d413-4c94-8a7a-38dac30cbed6

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "take a look at them"?

The question can be interpreted in some many ways.

The easiest is to display the drawing explorer. It will show you the structure of your drawing, including groups and subshapes.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-your-drawing-using-the-drawing-explorer-window-81502ef3-6cac-423e-b4f1-1c19a5126e70?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Maybe you want a form in which in which you display the groups of the drawing. Then you would need to be able to identify them. The easiest way would be to iterate over all shapes of the drawing and to check whether they have subshapes.

```
Sub find_groups()
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes
        If shp.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print shp.ID; " is a group"
        Else
            Debug.Print shp.ID; " is not a group"
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Or maybe you want a report of the groups, then you need first to mark them as groups by a field that you fill by something like the above code.

... so many interpretations.

Comment: sorry, if it's confusing. I want to see all shapes in all groups like we do when we choose one: https://prnt.sc/t4sblu.

Comment: Just updated the image in the question for clarification.

Comment: Alright, got you now. You want to see all the available MASTERS of a STENCIL. Unfortunately, you are already seeing all of them (your picture). What you can further do is explore manually the available stencils. Note that you can open several stencils at once and you can also try the search function (although it does not work reliably).

Comment: These are called "stencil categories" in Visio-speak. Visio Standard has certain categories, the Pro version adds more, and 3rd-party addins can add any category they like as well as extend what is already there.